# unable to show loading spinner image when the page is loading for the second time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show the loading spinner when page is loading/waiting to get the response from backend.
Below code loads the pdf file and show on webpage. Initially the loading icon is seen when the pdf is still loading. But for the second time when clicked on Regenerate button to regenerate the pdf and load pdf again,the old PDF is seen on the webpage instead i want to show loading spinner icon and then load the response(instead of showing old pdf and then load the response).
Or i can even show the loading spinner icon near the `Reload data button` till the new response is loaded.

html code:

```
    <table style="width:100%;height:80%;" ng-controller="loadingSampleCtrl">
<tr> <td><button type="button" ng-click="fileRead()">Reload data</button></td></tr>

         <tr ng-show="loading"> <td colspan="5" style="white-space: nowrap;text-align: center; font-size:36px;"><div class="loader"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ></i> Loading<span class="loader__dot">.</span><span class="loader__dot">.</span><span class="loader__dot">.</span></div></td></tr>
         <object-reloadable></object-reloadable>
         </table>
```

js code:

```
app.directive('objectReloadable', function() {
      var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var currentElement = element;

        scope.$watch('pdfName', function(newValue, oldValue) {
             if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                 scope.loading = false;
                 scope.pdfName = newValue;
                 var html = '<object style="width: 100%; height: 1200px;overflow-y: hidden; cursor:pointer;" type="application/pdf" data="' + scope.pdfName.filePath + '" ></object>';
                 var replacementElement = angular.element(html);
                currentElement.replaceWith(replacementElement);
                currentElement = replacementElement;
            }
        });
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        link: link
    };
})

myApp.controller('loadingSampleCtrl', function ($scope, FilesService) {
      $scope.loadData = function () {
      $scope.loading = true;
        FilesService.fileRead().then(
            function (response) {
                 $scope.filePathAndName = response;
                   if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
                    $scope.IEBrowser = true;
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.pdfName = response;
                        var html = '<object type="application/pdf" data="' + newValue + '"></object>';
                         var replacementElement = angular.element(html);
                         currentElement.replaceWith(replacementElement);
                         currentElement = replacementElement;*/
                    }, 0);
                } else {
                    $scope.IEBrowser = false;
                    $scope.filePathAndName = response;
                     $scope.loading = false;
                 }
            },
          function (errResponse) {
                $rootScope.showError("Internal error" + errResponse);
            });

    }
   $scope.loadData();
});
```

css for loading spinner:

```
<style>
    @keyframes blink {50% { color: transparent }}
    .loader__dot { animation: 1s blink infinite }
    .loader__dot:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 250ms }
    .loader__dot:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 500ms }

</style>
```

I have tried using  `$scope.loading = true;`(or false accordingly) but the result is not as expected.

--EDIT--
Below is the updated js code:
OnClick of Reload button, it calls the loadingSampleCtrl, `$scope.loadData = function ()`

Updated js code:

```
app.directive('objectReloadable', function() {
          var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var currentElement = element;

            scope.$watch('pdfName', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                 if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                     scope.loading = false;
                     scope.pdfName = newValue;
                     scope.html = '<object style="width: 100%; height: 1200px;overflow-y: hidden; cursor:pointer;" type="application/pdf" data="' + scope.pdfName.filePath + '" ></object>';
                     var replacementElement = angular.element(scope.html);
                    currentElement.replaceWith(replacementElement);
                    currentElement = replacementElement;
                }
            });
        };
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: false,
            link: link
        };
    })

    myApp.controller('loadingSampleCtrl', function ($scope, FilesService) {
          $scope.loadData = function () {
          $scope.loading = true;
$scope.html='';
            FilesService.fileRead().then(
                function (response) {
                     $scope.filePathAndName = response;
                       if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
                        $scope.IEBrowser = true;
                        $timeout(function() {
                            $scope.pdfName = response;
                           }, 0);
                    } else {
                        $scope.IEBrowser = false;
                        $scope.filePathAndName = response;
                         $scope.loading = false;
                     }
                },
              function (errResponse) {
                    $rootScope.showError("Internal error" + errResponse);
                });

        }
       $scope.loadData();
    });
```

With the above mentioned js code also , i'm facing the same issue. Onclick of Reload button,unable to see loading icon.

Comment: have you tried unsetting the pdfname variable ( setting it equal to empty object ) when button is clicked ?

Comment: no, i have not tired it. How can i do it , as i'm creating that dynamically in runtime. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you, if you can create a fiddle for your code.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I had mentioned below to call a function on ng-click which you seem to have missed.

This should work:

when the `Reload data button` is clicked, call a function like:

replace var html with $scope.html;
You are declaring html variable twice;

```
function reloadData(){
  $scope.pdfName = {};
  $scope.html = '';
  $scope.loadData();
}
```

Please change the name of the variables as per your code.

Comment: Please see my html code, i just added the button code,<tr> <td><button type="button" ng-click="fileRead()">Reload data</button></td></tr> I am calling the same fileRead() button which i'm actually using first time while generating the pdf. Can i still use the solution you suggested?

Comment: in your controller add the above function and map it to your button, it should work.

Comment: I just noticed with my code or your code, it is showing the loading icon when i click the Reload data button, but somewhere down it is showing, i need to scroll the page down to see it. I think it is showing the loading icon after the pdf displayed area..Any suggestions?

Comment: clear the html variable as well.
include  var html = ' ';  in your function reloadData.

check the answer, I've edited it to add this case.

Comment: Still its the same issue, please see my post above, i have given the updated js code in edited section of my post. Still cannot able to show the Reload icon in place of the html section, instead the pdf displayed section is becoming blank and the Reload icon is displayed down to that blank space which i need to scroll down to see the icon.

Comment: As @Aditya mentioned in his answer, you need to call reloadData on ng-click of your button. This should fix the issue. I'm editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

on ng-click you are directly calling fileread. Instead call loadData. then it should work ( the reason being you are setting $scope.loading to true inside loadData)